# How to do data augmentation on an 8 by 8 greyscale image?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras, grayscale, data-augmentation

I want to to data augmentation on an 8*8-pixel greayscale image through the codes below on Keras (the pixel values are only 0 and 1):

```
from ctypes import sizeof
from re import X
from turtle import shape
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from skimage import io
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=45,     #Random rotation between 0 and 45
        width_shift_range=0.2,   #% shift
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode='nearest')    #Also try nearest, constant, reflect, wrap

    
# forming a binary 8*8 array
array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0], 
 [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

# scale values to uint8 maximum 255, and convert it to greyscale image
array = ((array) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
x = Image.fromarray(array)


i = 0
for batch in datagen.flow(x, batch_size=16,  
                          save_to_dir='augmented', 
                          save_prefix='aug', 
                          save_format='png'):
i += 1
if i > 20:
    break  # otherwise the generator would loop indefinitely
```

But I get this error in the output (when I have `.flow` function):

```
ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (8, 8))
```

Could anyone give me some hands please?

Comment: Do you know what the meaning of an array’s rank is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageDataGenerator` accepts input as 4-dimensional tensor, where first dimension is sample number and last dimension are color channels. In your code you should convert this `(8,8)` tensor to `(1,8,8,1)` tensor. This can be done by

```py
array = np.expand_dims(array, (0, -1))
```

Also you should not convert array to image before passing it to generator as you did it here

```py
x = Image.fromarray(array)
```

you should simply pass `array` to generator.